# Why we generally ignore SIGCHLD

Tags: c, signals, sigchld

I was studying about signals and going through this link

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Child_process#cite_note-1

And this is what it says : "The SIGCHLD signal is sent to the parent of a child process when it exits, is interrupted, or resumes after being interrupted. By default the signal is simply ignored"

is there any reason why we ignore SIGCHLD.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try having kids and you'll understand why sometimes you have to ignore `SIGCHLD` to maintain your sanity :).

Jokes aside, all that statement means is that POSIX systems do not define a default signal behavior, other than to ignore it, for SIGCHLD.   Compare this with `SIGINT`, `SIGTERM`, etc where the default behavior might be to terminate the process.

See `man 7 signal` on linux for a list of all signals, all default handlers, and the mapping of signals->default handler.

Often it makes sense to ignore SIGCHLD because you can know everything you need to know from `waitpid`.

Comment: hehehe, nice joke, anyway you clarified my doubt ..thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Even though my answer is late, it might be helpful for a wonderer person thinking reason for need of `SIGCHLD` and why it is ignored. Let's listen my story.

I've taken a project in which we are streaming online radio stations whose extensions are `.pls`, `.m3u` or just `IP:Port`. Each station is a channel for us. There are two doodads - a [potentiometer](http://www.resistorguide.com/potentiometer/) and a [rotary encoder](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Rotary_encoder) - which are able to be rotated(switched) either clockwise or counter clockwise. The former is used to adjust volume of the radio, likewise the latter is to change channels. I'm using a media player working via terminal, so it is also **another process**. Likewise, I'm using [amixer](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-amixer/) which is also **additional another process** to adjust volume abruptly within a while infinite loop . In the main process, I create two processes. To change channel I opt to send SIGKILL signal to terminate the player process which is liable to play selected station to go new channel and `wait()` in parent. `wait()` usage is appropriate here because I had killed him before I waited. It would immediately returns without blocking. On the volume changer's side, it works until radio device is turned off. Its process is being run in an infinite loop.

> So, what would be happen if I opt to make wait its parent process for the volume adjuster process?

The main process would block forever since the volume adjuster process would never return. In lieu, I opt to handle explicitly but in ignoring way. **Why?** Because I don't care when it is terminated or what its return value is. I only care that after its termination, **I don't want the child to turn into a zombie. I just want when the child exits it is reaped immediately as well as non-blocking main process.**

> Why do we generally ignore `SIGCHLD`?

If (as in the aforementioned example) the signal handler does nothing beyond calling `waitpid` then an alternative is available. Setting the `SIGCHLD` handler to `SIG_IGN` will cause zombie processes to be reaped automatically.

Don't forget that to do that, explicitly calling `sigaction()` with the disposition `SIG_IGN` is needed.